expl3: fully expandable reformatting of comma-delimited text
I am trying to change the delimiter of comma-separated values (e.g., "a,b,c" -> "a-b-c") in a manner that normalizes input by trimming whitespace and removing empty entries (e.g., ", a,b  ,c,," -> "a-b-c").  I just learned expl3, and the l3clist module makes a non-expandable solution absolutely trivial to write:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__str_tmp_cl %module: "str"
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \__str_join_csv:nn {
        \clist_set:Nn \l__str_tmp_cl { #2 }
        \clist_use:Nn \l__str_tmp_cl { #1 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__str_join_csv:nn { ee }
\NewDocumentCommand{\strjoin}{ m m } {
        \__str_join_csv:ee { #1 } { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
        \def\delimVar{-}
        \strjoin{\delimVar}{a,}\par
        \strjoin{\delimVar}{a,b}\par
        \strjoin{\delimVar}{,a,b,c,}\par
        \def\csvVar{a,b,,c,d,}
        \strjoin{\delimVar}{\csvVar}\par
\end{document}

This produces the following output:
a
a-b
a-b-c
a-b-c-d

However, I would like a fully expandable solution, so that I can place the command directly in an edef-like expansion context such as \typeout, \message, or \TEST{\str_if_eq:VVTF{\testObserved}{\testExpected}{\TYPE{passed}}{\TYPE{failed}}} (the latter using l3build).  However, my attempt at a recursive solution has ended in failure, which may be due to inadequate understanding of the use of the \q_stop quark.  I include my attempt below.  The typeout prints the string verbatim; the following call causes pdflatex to hang, presumably due to infinite recursion.
\ExplSyntaxOn

%\__str_join_csv:w
%       #1 = delimiter
%       #2 = text accumulated so far
%       #3 = next token, up to the next comma (possibly empty)
%       #4 = remaining CSV (or \q_stop)
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \__str_join_csv:w #1 #2 #3 , #4 \q_stop {
        \str_if_eq:nnTF { #4 } {\q_stop} { %reached final token
                \str_if_eq:nnTF { #3 } { } {
                        #2
                } {
                        \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { } { #3 } { #2 #1 #3 }
                }
        } { %more tokens to parse
                \str_if_eq:nnTF { #3 } { } {
                        \__str_join_csv:w { #1 } { #2 } #4 , \q_stop
                } {
                        \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { } {
                                \__str_join_csv:w { #1 }       { #3 } #4 , \q_stop
                        } {
                                \__str_join_csv:w { #1 } { #2 #1 #3 } #4 , \q_stop
                        }
                }
        }
}

%\str_join_csv_start:nn { <delim> } { <csv> }
\cs_new_nopar:Nn \str_join_csv_start:nn {
        %initiate recursion with
        %       an empty accumulator
        %       trailing comma and \q_stop
        \__str_join_csv:w { #1 } { }    #2 , \q_stop
        %                 delim  accum  csv
}

%wrapper
\NewDocumentCommand{\strjoin}{m m} {
        \str_join_csv_start:nn {#1}{#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
        \typeout{\strjoin{-}{a,b,c}}
        \strjoin{-}{a,b,c}
\end{document}

The output is as follows, including a SIGINT (^c) at the point the program hangs.
\strjoin {-}{a,b,c}
^C! Interruption.
(...)

I'm stymied, and hoping someone can point me in the right direction as to the cause of the infinite recursion.  Many thanks in advance.

Unrelated, but commands defined with \NewDocumentCommand are never expandable (that's why typeout doesn't expand it)

@UlrikeFischer: Thanks, I forgot that I need to use \NewExpandableDocumentCommand!

What's wrong with \clist_use:nn?
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\changesep}{mm}
 {
  \clist_use:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\changesep{a,b,c}{-}

\changesep{, a , b,c }{-}

\edef\test{\changesep{a,b,c}{x}}

\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}


Adapting to your \strjoin:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\strjoin}{mm}
 {
  \clist_use:ee {#2} {#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_use:nn {ee}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\delimVar{-}
\strjoin{\delimVar}{a,}\par
\strjoin{\delimVar}{a,b}\par
\strjoin{\delimVar}{,a,b,c,}\par
\def\csvVar{a,b,,c,d,}
\strjoin{\delimVar}{\csvVar}\par

\end{document}



Thanks --- I was under the (evidently mistaken) impression that \clist_use could only be applied to an existing clist data structure created by an assignment operation like \clist_set.

Because I don't like expl3, I can show you what to do at TeX primitive level:
\def\strjoin#1{\expandafter\strjoinAns#1,\end,}
\def\strjoinA #1,{%
   \ifx,#1,\expandafter\strjoinAns
   \else \ifx\end#1\else \nolastspace#1\fin/ \fin\relax{#1}%
                         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \strjoinBns
   \fi   \fi
}
\def\strjoinB #1,{%
   \ifx\end#1\empty\else
      \ifx,#1,\else \delimVar\nolastspace#1\fin/ \fin\relax{#1}\fi
   \expandafter\strjoinBns\fi
}
\def\strjoinAns{\expandafter\strjoinA\romannumeral-`\.}
\def\strjoinBns{\expandafter\strjoinB\romannumeral-`\.}
\def\nolastspace#1 \fin#2\relax#3{\ifx,#2,#3\else#1\fi}

\def\delimVar{-}
\strjoin{a,}\par
\strjoin{a,b}\par
\strjoin{,a,b,c,}\par
\def\csvVar{a,b,,c,d,}
\strjoin\csvVar\par

\bye

First, we ignore all empty items (first comma or comma comma) in \strjoinA loop and we put first nonempty item. Then, the \strjoinB loop adds \delimVar item for each non-empty item.

This doesn't answer the question, which asked for space strippong, try \def\csvVar{a, b,,c ,d,}

OK, I didn't noticed tha space stripping is needed too. I supposed that this is done before the macro is used. I added space stripping to my code.

Thanks for the TeX solution --- very impressive.
